# strange behaviour of sqlite3_step (does not move to the next row)

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

Roughly I have this code:

```objc
querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id, contactid, txtcontent, strDate, direction, status, priority, status_r....."
const char * query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
if(sqlite3_prepare(db, query_stmt, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
    int rc;
    while ((rc = sqlite3_step(statement)) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        ....
    }
}
```

On any iPhone running 9.x, there is no problem and the app is reading every time a new row.
On any iPhone 4 running 7.x the exactly same code stays on the same row and enters a dead end loop.
Anybody having had this problem?

Comment: Show the preceding code.

Comment: The code is long but still executes perfectly on an iphone5, 6, ipad running 9.x  querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id, contactid, txtcontent, strDate, direction, status, priority, status_r.....
  const char * query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_prepare(db, query_stmt, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            int rc;
            while ((rc = sqlite3_step(statement)) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
    ....
   }
  }

Comment: I have just added sqlite3_errmsg(db) in the loop, and I indeed can see the error message: unknown error (100). But still strange that the code is 100 which is in fact SQLITE_ROW. Is there a way to diagnose the problem?

Comment: What is in the part of the query that you omitted?

Comment: I have now truncated the query to something very simple: querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id, contactid from messages"]; and it still happens

Comment: And if I extract the database from the device and manually Execute one of the queries in SQLPro for instance, either the complex or the simple one, everything works

Answer (score 0):

It finally appears that the query was something like

```
querySQL = "select * from messages order by date desc, date desc";
```

where the order condition mistakenly appeared twice and this caused the sqlite3_step to stay on the same row. This same code worked several years without any problem and still works and higher iOS levels. Strange.